# borderRadius doesn't work on image when resizeMode is set to 'contain'

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been trying to build an Image carousel with a bunch of randomly selected images. I wanted to maintain their aspect ratios so I set the resizeMode to 'contain'. Somehow that step leads to the loss of any set borderRadius! What could be the reason? And if that step doesn't work at all, any other ideas on how to maintain the correct aspect ratio + get the corners rounded?

Thanks a lot for your help!

here's the code:

```
import React, { useCallback, memo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
} from "react-native";


const images = [
  Image1,
  Image2,
  Image3,
  Image4,
  Image5,
  Image6,
  Image7,
  Image8,
  Image9,
  Image10,
  Image11,
  Image12,
  Image13,
  Image14,
  Image15,
  Image16,
  Image17,
  Image18,
  Image19,
  Image20,
  Image21,
  Image22,
  Image23,
  Image24,
  Image25,
  Image26,
  Image27,
  Image28,
  Image29,
  Image30,
  Image31,
  Image32,
  Image33,
  Image34,
  Image35,
  Image36,
  Image37,
  Image38,
  Image39,
  Image40,
  Image41,
]


const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");



const randomImage = () =>
images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  slide: {
    height: windowHeight,
    width: windowWidth,
    //justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  slideImage: { 
    height: '70%',
    width: '90%',
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    
   },
 
  slideTitle: { 
    fontSize: 24,
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  slideSubtitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginTop: 10,
  },

  pagination: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 8,
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 12
  },
  paginationDot: {
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    marginHorizontal: 2,
  },
  paginationDotActive: { backgroundColor: "lightblue" },
  paginationDotInactive: { backgroundColor: "gray" },

  carousel: {},
});

const slideList = Array.from({ length: 999 }).map((_, i) => {
  return {
    id: i,
    image: randomImage,
    title: `This is the title ${i + 1}!`,
    subtitle: `This is the subtitle ${i + 1}!`,
  };
});

const Slide = memo(function Slide({ data }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.slide}>
      <Image resizeMode = 'contain' source = {randomImage()} style={styles.slideImage}></Image>
      <Text style={styles.slideTitle}>{data.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.slideSubtitle}>{data.subtitle}</Text>
    </View>
  );
});

function Pagination({ index }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.pagination} pointerEvents="none">
      {slideList.map((_, i) => {
        return (
          <View
            key={i}
            style={[
              styles.paginationDot,
              index === i
                ? styles.paginationDotActive
                : styles.paginationDotInactive,
            ]}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

export default function Carousel() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const indexRef = useRef(index);
  indexRef.current = index;
  const onScroll = useCallback((event) => {
    const slideSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
    const index = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / slideSize;
    const roundIndex = Math.round(index);

    const distance = Math.abs(roundIndex - index);

    // Prevent one pixel triggering setIndex in the middle
    // of the transition. With this we have to scroll a bit
    // more to trigger the index change.
    const isNoMansLand = 0.4 < distance;

    if (roundIndex !== indexRef.current && !isNoMansLand) {
      setIndex(roundIndex);
    }
  }, []);

  const flatListOptimizationProps = {
    initialNumToRender: 0,
    maxToRenderPerBatch: 1,
    removeClippedSubviews: true,
    scrollEventThrottle: 16,
    windowSize: 2,
    keyExtractor: useCallback(s => String(s.id), []),
    getItemLayout: useCallback(
      (_, index) => ({
        index,
        length: windowWidth,
        offset: index * windowWidth,
      }),
      []
    ),
  };

  const renderItem = useCallback(function renderItem({ item }) {
    return <Slide data={item} />;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        data={slideList}
        style={styles.carousel}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        pagingEnabled
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        {...flatListOptimizationProps}
      />
      <Pagination index={index}></Pagination>
    </>
  );
}
 ``
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually `borderRadius` works but you can't see it because of an incorrect ratio.

If your image has a 16:9 ratio, for example, 1600x900 dimensions, then you need to set `width` and `height` with the same ratio.

```
<Image
    source={ 1600x900 }
    resizeMode="contain"
    style={{
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        borderRadius: 15,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }} />
```

The result will be:

[image]

Because the image has width and height 300, ie 1:1 ratio. If you modify `width` and `height` like `320` and `180`, ie 16:9, then the image fills all the space and borders will be visible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer! very helpful and makes a lot of sense! Do you have an idea what I can do in order to keep the rounded corners when the images I import have different aspect ratios? they're basically 3/4 either in landscape or portrait mode!

Comment: `cover` looks bad?

Comment: cover cuts off parts of the images that don't fit into the given style(width/height) for the image :/. Is it possible to somehow connect an If statement to the style? so if it's one of the landscape photos, the hight/width gets set accordingly , and for the portrait ones the same? Thanks for your time!:)

Comment: How can you determine the landscape photo?

Comment: I got the photographs in a folder and I would just check which ones are landscape and which ones are portrait :D

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to wrap your image with view that hides the overflow

```
 <View
     style={{
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        borderRadius: 150,
        overflow: 'hidden',
     }}
>
     <Image
        source={item.image}
        style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
        }}
        resizeMode='contain'
     />
</View>
```